# how to select option to submit different php page

Tags: php, forms, submit

drop down select "sales" go to sales.php, other options selected go to addFund.php...

```
<form name='searform' method='post' action='<?php echo $home;?>addFund.php'>
Search : <input type='text' id='sear' name='sear'> by 
<select id='psel' name='psel' onchange='change()'>
<option value='email'>Email</option>
<option value='name'>Username</option>
<option value='domain'>Domain name</option>
<option value='sales'>Sales</option>
</select>
<input type='submit' name='sub' id='sub' value='Go' onclick='gopage()'>
<input type='submit' name='dir' id='dir' value='Direct'>
</form>
```

How to submit different pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with javascript:

```
function change(el) {
  if(el.value === 'sales') {
    el.form.action = 'sales.php';
  } else {
    el.form.action = 'addFund.php';
  }
}
```

Change the onchange to `onchange="change(this)"`. A better way would be to check the variable on serverside and include the right file.

Comment: how to call this change() function? "go"  button onclick event or onsubmit()?

Comment: You would put this in the `onchange=` attribute of the `<select>` (as it does clearly say above)

Comment: @jey you have already a `onchange='change()'` in your `select`. Just add `this` to change and it should work. This calls the change() method when you select an entry. You may need to add my code to an existing function...

Comment: @binarious: i put in code.. its works.. The search code used all pages "header.php".but single issue.. i select "sales" go to sales.php. then email is selected default option.so submit go to addFund.php. but again go to sales.php.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some Javascript nastiness to achieve this with the `change()` function, but the usual way to do this is to route all requests through a controller and `include()` the appropriate page. For example, point your form to `action.php`, and in that file, do this:

action.php

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['psel']) && $_POST['psel'] == 'sales') {
    include 'sales.php';
  } else {
    include 'addFund.php';
  }
```

...or you could just put roughly that code into `addFund.php`, since you only seem to have one other script that you would want to send requests to.

Answer (score -1):

Change your select to this:

```
<select name="vote" onChange="document.forms['searForm'].submit()">
```

And make your form action go to something like pageChange.php where it returns a different page depending on the `$_POST` value.